# Android: Tag child element of a view on touch_down event

Tags: android, view, drawing, android-recyclerview, touch-event

I have this architecture (ViewGroup with a View and RecyclerView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.wacom.matchapoc.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <com.wacom.matchapoc.view.SmartRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <com.wacom.matchapoc.view.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawingView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The `DrawingView` is ontop of the `RecyclerView` and has an Overridden `onTouch()` event, so that when `isEnableDrawing()` flag is true (you can set it from the settings in the main activity) it handles the touch_down/move/up events so that you can draw over the elements in the `RecyclerView`.

What I want to do now is essentially to link the user-made drawings on the `DrawingView` to the child elements (text, pictures etc.) of the `RecyclerView`. To do that I need to know which child element of the `RecyclerView` is under the initial `touch_down(x,y)` coordinates, tag it and then continue drawing.

Currently I have these problems:

1. I'm not sure whether the `getFocusedChild()` method of the `RecyclerView` will correctly return the child element that is under the `touch_down(x,y)`;
2. In order to let the touch event through to the `RecyclerView`, I need to not consume it in the `DrawingView`, then tag the child element in the `RecyclerView` and not consume it again, then return it to the `DrawingView` and continue with the drawing.

This is proving rather difficult for me since I've only recently started Android programming and am not all that familiar with the API and how it works.

Any suggestions about how to link/tag the child elements so that I can easily know which drawing/path belongs to which child element would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's a method in `RecyclerView` called [findChildViewUnder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findChildViewUnder(float,%20float)) which does exactly what I needed.